# episodic jdbc insert and update slowly

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am monitoring via SkyWalking that there are occasional inserts and updates that are executing very slowly at the Mysql/JDBI/PreparedStatement/execute endpoints.
[monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frXDJ.png)
[monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egwur.png)

environments:
mysql: read committed
: 8.0.23

We started with a Druid link pool and I started to suspect that it was bug, so we switched to a HikariCP link pool, but we still have the problem. Since we don't have access to the database host, we can't see the IO statistics of the database. I asked the DBA for the logs of the slow SQL, but there is no corresponding slow SQL, so the consensus is that it's a Java code problem, and I've ruled out that there is no big transaction where the slow SQL in question is concerned. I wanted to ask if you have come across this or how can I go about troubleshooting this.

If there is no solution, I can only suspect that it might be due to a poor server configuration. This is only the case with some of the tables.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) . Also check out the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and 
[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: We will need minimum of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; B) Your complete query, C) EXPLAIN INSERT (rest of your query);  Welcome to SO.